# What should our chat room name be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Right now, our chat room's name is just [**Pets**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/pets). I think we can do better than that, what sort of clever and appropriate name could we use instead?

Answer (score 12):

Since I got convinced to propose it, how about **"The Litter Box"** which is oddly appropriate since chat is the place to go when it's not appropriate on the site...

Comment: This is too cat specific and I think could encourage poor behavior.  I urge the community to choose something different.

Comment: @Chad - propose an alternate name or encourage an existing alternate name if you don't like it.

Comment: @JoshDM - There are several here already...  It is more the fact that every time i have to click the link it makes my skin crawl.

Comment: @Chad - then it's a good thing you don't know the true meaning behind the act of performing a "Stack Exchange", otherwise you'd never visit this site.

Comment: @JoshDM - Thats just Ewww.... Besides a stack exchange is the process changing order of operations on items in on the Stack(a memory register) not something... EWWWWW

Comment: This made me chuckle when I saw it (hence my previous comment and upvote), but I would retract that upvote now if I could because of the "ewww" factor that turns off some others.  In the interest of friendliness we should consider alternatives.

Comment: I threw it out there for humor, I was actually surprised it climbed the voting ladder...

Answer (score 7):

**"The Water Bowl"** might work well as a general, species non-specific name.

Comment: I like this name.  It's like the water cooler (where people gather at work), but not. :-)

Comment: While I'm a fan of humor (The Litter Box), this proposal is actually the best one here, paws down.  Much better than your Menagerie suggestion.

Comment: OK, now I prefer either this or "Table Scraps" over "The Litter Box".

Answer (score 3):

The Shelter is one species neutral idea but is somewhat sad by certain associations.

Answer (score 3):

"The Burrow"

[A burrow is a hole or tunnel excavated into the ground by an animal to create a space suitable for habitation, temporary refuge, or as a byproduct of locomotion. Burrows provide a form of shelter against predation and exposure to the elements, so the burrowing way of life is quite popular among the animals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrow)

It is where you go to feel safe, you can be yourself and let your hair down. Usually there is a back door so you can leave when ever you feel the need, and of course all of your friends are there :)

Comment: [Kafka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Burrow_%28short_story%29) reference?  Or maybe [Harry Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Places_in_Harry_Potter#The_Burrow)?

Comment: @BenMiller, anything you want.  There are multiple references, everyone can pick there own.

Answer (score 2):

**Vivarium**

> (Latin, literally for *"place of life"*; plural: *vivaria* or *vivariums*) is an area, usually enclosed, for keeping and raising animals or plants for observation or research. Often, a
>   portion of the ecosystem for a particular species is simulated on a
>   smaller scale, with controls for environmental conditions.

Quote is from [Wikipedia on Vivarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivarium). I think this fits the bill perfectly. Single, easy to remember word, and doesn't really exclude any animal species. It also has a ring to it suggesting a lively, vibrant place.

Comment: Not a good name, for one who does not know what it means. You seem to have your doubts too, for including a dictionary excerpt with the name.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto No, I have absolutely no problems understanding its meaning, or thinking that others here might not. It's as simple Latin as it gets really and anyone at least half-literate shouldn't have problems either. The quote is there more as an anchor, I do apologize if anyone found it too patronizing. Anyway, it's just a suggestion, no harm done if some other is / will be used. ;)

Comment: My language (Finnish) is not a decendant of Germanic/Latin languages. Vivarium has no meaning to me, I have no clue of what it might translate to. Though now I have, thanks to you :)

Comment: @EsaPaulasto Well, in truth you are writing in English, which does tend to use many words of Latin origin. _Vivo_ itself and its derivatives are common words in biology, study of life in general, and even music. And its suffix is the same as for _terrarium_, _aquarium_, etc. English translations often just replace _-rium_ with _-ry_, e.g. _estuarium_ is _estuary_, _ovarium_ is _ovary_,... while the base stays the same.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Chad's [chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12027316#12027316), I present to you, **"Table Scraps"**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would be a good name: "The Kennel"

Comment: The Kennel looks good to me.

Comment: I like kennel, but as far as I know is very dog-focused.

Comment: @Baarn you made me agree with you.

Comment: Well, there goes my idea of "The Dog House", which should be the chat room for marriage.SE.com

Comment: Tempted to propose "The Litter Box" now... :D

Answer (score 1):

**"The Menagerie"** is a good name for a collection of pets and also for a collection of users.

Comment: I had to look Menagerie up in dictionary to understand what the word means. Not good for non-english speakers. ([menagerie](http://glosbe.com/en/fi/menagerie) = A collection of live wild animals on exhibition; the enclosure where they are kept.)

Answer (score -1):

How about the name of a classic movie: "Animal House"

Answer (score -1):

Chat room name should reflect the name of the main site.

**"The Pets Chat"** follows a common naming style of [StackExchange chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all).

Comment: No, I don't support this name myself, but I think this is one option that needs to be on this list.

Answer (score -2):

The Den is a species neutral name but may be too "wild" for this site.

Answer (score -4):

I propose "The Yard".  I dislike the current "The Litter Box" for two reasons.

For one, I agree it primarily evokes thoughts of cats (and while I like cats, not all of our visitors will be cat people).

For another, while it is cute, I feel its a bit too cute.  Not everyone shares the same sense of humor.

I'm all for a catchy, amusing name, and I realize that "the Yard" doesn't really qualify on either counts, but I think it is better than one that evokes strong imagery of a specific type of pet (let alone the other imagery that comes to mind with the current name!).

Comment: I am with you here...

Answer (score -5):

How about the...

**Pet Parlour**

Answer (score -6):

How about this for a name:  "The Zoo"

Comment: -1, not agree with Zoo. No offend but we are discussing about pet not wild animals kept in bars.

Answer (score -6):

"The Stables", which I believe is pretty common expression for a base of some sort.

Comment: for me it sounds too much like cattle and not pets.

Answer (score -7):

"All Creatures Great and Small"

Answer (score -7):

"Animals and the Pets Who Love Them"

Comment: It's a little long; take a look at the space available for the name in other chat rooms.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Since there is the ability to create rooms with "Room for jonsca and UserWithALongNameEtcEtc", I don't think that there's any actual limitation.  From a practical standpoint, it may be a different issue

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10991/test-for-number-of-characters-that-can-be-used-in-a-chat-room-description

Answer (score -10):

I suggest "Nonhuman family members"

Answer (score -14):

I would not go for any confined place for the animals here. I would suggest "The Free World" where the pets go free and can do whatever they like.

Comment: I have several associations with "free world" but I'd never think of pets.

Comment: Poor wording choice, setting a pet "Free" does not make it free, it makes it dead, in most unpleasant ways.