# Renaming The Litter Box?

Tags: discussion, chat

Currently the chat room name is "The Litter Box". Some users think this is an inappropriate name.
The "The Menagerie" has been the [runner up](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/100/58) for a few days now.

"The Litter Box" has +18/-4 votes, "The Menagerie" has +12/-1, making it the less controversial one.

I wonder how the community thinks of changing the name to the less controversial, yet less popular name?

Comment: Wait... do meta upvotes on this count as agreeing to rename (with downvotes disagreeing to rename), or agreeing to discuss renaming?

Comment: @JoshDM votes on the question itself would only mean that you think this topic is worth discussing (regardless of the result). Please voice your opinion voting on one (or both) of the questions.

Comment: I was being a smart@$$.

Comment: And I was just being a Mod ;)

Comment: Also, it's kind of nonsensical to have two questions because if we're going between the two, what if someone up-votes one but doesn't down-vote the other?  Since it was posted first, "conceptually" R2TM will get the most vote attention.  Then-again, it might not.  I'd just have one question: RtLB2tM

Comment: @JoshDM I think you mean answers? I think that having an answer for each choice has some advantages, as it provides more possible options. While It might be true for answers with long text, I doubt people wont be reading the second option in this specific case.

Comment: Baarn (just for future reference): It is typically better to open a topic to broader discussion rather than polling with this type of pre-posted answer format. It's more engaging to infer what the community wants from the conversation rather trying to drive consensus with this *vote-on-my-options* format. It gives everyone a voice. **[Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion)** . Just a heads up. Thanks.

Comment: @Skippy In my experience, part of being a moderator, particularly during beta, includes initiating discussions on key issues.  Note that this responsibility is not limited to moderators! However, moderators are frequently in an advantageous position to be aware of the most contentious points that are causing discontent or discord within the community.  There's a distinction between taking charge of the community, and being a leader within the community. Anyone who steps up to the plate can be a leader within the community, but *all* moderators should fall within that category.

Comment: Keep in mind that it can always be changed again if folks want.

Comment: Big proponent of "The Water Bowl" over either of these.

Comment: The funny thing is that I voted for "The Menagerie" since that was what my family used to call my pet collection...

Comment: How about a trivial edit in the answers to allow a change of mind for them who have already voted? Or, if the vote has been completed already, add a "Status-complete" tag to the question, right?

Comment: @EsaPaulasto I am very allergic to the whole "edit to reconsider votes"-thing. This isn't how the voting mechanics is supposed to work, and I dislike gaming the system. I think we shouldn't tag it status complete as it might be - especially as we are in beta - still something we might want to reconsider if another answer accumulates enough votes.

Comment: @Baarn Given the nature of meta, I feel that edit-to-change-votes is a bit less of an offense here than on the main site. Sidebar discussions that are more appropriate outside of meta posts are a legitimate means of changing one's mind, even after a vote is registered.

Comment: Closing it, as its purpose is fulfilled

Comment: Showinhg up with a reopen request, where closed as a duplicate and no reason to reopen given.  Leave closed.

Answer (score 11):

Don't rename, keep **"The Litter Box"**.

Answer (score 3):

Rename to **"The Menagerie"**.

Answer (score 3):

Rename to **"The Water Bowl"** which is currently in second place on [What should our chat room name be?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-should-our-chat-room-name-be), behind the "The Litter Box".

Comment: I am just posting the answer, because it should be here.  Not actively supporting it.

Comment: This one is my favorite.